# An expanded take on Stars Druid Dragon form and Polymorph

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, conditions

My initial question got closed so I'm asking again because the answers in the referenced questions are inconclusive.

Consider these sequences:

A. Ally A Polymorphs a PC into a giant ape then ally B cast Light on the same PC.
The logical result would seem to be a glowing giant ape. The alternative result
of Polymorph being replaced with a glowing (human, elf ...) seems incorrect as it
implies that polymorph can be dispelled with a cantrip.

B. Ally B cast Light on a PC first and then ally A Polymorphs the same PC into a giant ape.
The same spells are cast except in different order. Is casting order relevant?
If not then the end result is the same as in sequence A, a glowing giant ape. Otherwise casting order matters with
the implication that Polymorph can dispel pre-existing conditions such as Fear or Charm.
And that is a significant power boost for Polymorph.

Back to the Circle of Stars druid.

> While in your starry form, you retain your game statistics, but your body becomes luminous; your joints glimmer like stars, and glowing lines connect them as on a star chart.

The starry form looks like a light spell although its a magical affect. Logically it should have the same Polymorph interaction as casting the Light cantrip.

I'm trying to understand the implications.

Comment: Please *revise* your original question rather than reposting it to get around closure. Your original question was closed as a duplicate of several questions that ask “does [class feature] work when you polymorph?”, and the answers to those questions over the years have all come up with the same conclusion: *class features don’t work while you are polymorphed*. So is there something about Starry Form that *distinguishes* it from other class features, such that the last four times this question has been asked don’t apply to this particular feature?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I realize we're a number of dupeclosures deep, but I think a feature being activated before *polymorph* is a distinct from whether a polymorphed creature can activate a class feature (even if there cases of them having the same answer). I still think this should have been edited into its marker instead of reposted. (Sidenote about the examples in this version, I don't think it wholly invalidates you point CWallach, but *light* doesn't target a creature, but an object)

Comment: @Someone_Evil Then the question here is still a dupe of the rage and blade song questions if not the one I pointed all of those to.

Comment: @Someone_Evil a fair point, things should be straightened out now.